# Can @media used to trigger different Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to add ad code (javascript)  into my responsive design blog. But I'm not sure how to handle it. Can I make use of @media? I have two ads 728x90 and 320x50, both javascript code. I want to display 728x90 when width is greater than 730 else always 320x50. Is this possible?

My blog is a tumblr blog.

Comment: Why not use $(window).width() or screen.availWidth (or something similar) on page load? Then use logic to use either ad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following and see if it works:

```
jQuery(window).on('resize change', function () {
if(jQuery(window).width() > 730){
    Do something here...
}else{
    Do something here...
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS can't trigger JavaScript, but JavaScript can directly test media queries.

```
if (window.matchMedia("min-width: 730px").matches) {
  // show big ad
}
else {
  // show small add
}
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

Answer (score 0):

you can find the client window width with js and apply your logic accordingly

```
if (window.innerWidth > 730) {
  //your code here
} else {
  // code here
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp